# How do I find the area in the region inside the cardioid $r = 6 + 6\sin(\theta)$ and above the line $y = 9/2$

Tags: calculus

Image of graph [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IR0i.png)

I'm sure this is easy but I have looked everywhere and can't get an exact answer. Just having trouble figuring it out. I understand that you can find the area by having 2 radii but I am unaware on how to find with a line.

Comment: Hint: Represent the line in polar coordinates, and use the polar area formula.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please don’t rely solely on images to state your question; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, when you know how to solve a problem and come across a new problem, see if you can turn that new problem into a form where you can use techniques you know. In this case, you have a line $y = \frac{9}{2}$. The transformation from polar to Cartesian coordinates is given by $y = r \sin \theta$, so this shows you that the line can be represented as $\frac{9}{2} = r \sin \theta \implies r_2 (\theta) = \frac{9}{2} \csc \theta$.

The limits of integration are where $r_1 = r_2$ (where $r_1 (\theta)$ is the cardioid). Solving, we get

$$\frac{9}{2} \csc \theta = 6 + 6 \sin \theta \implies \frac{9}{2} = 6 \sin \theta + 6 \sin^2 \theta$$

Letting $C = \sin \theta$, the equation becomes a quadratic:

$$C^2 + C - \frac{3}{4} = 0 \implies \left( C + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = 1$$

so that $C = \frac{1}{2}$ or $C = -\frac{3}{2}$. Visually, you can verify that both intersection points are in the upper half-plane, so we must have $\sin \theta_{1, 2} = \frac{1}{2}$. The limits are $\theta_1 = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\theta_2 = \frac{5 \pi}{6}$.

The area integral becomes

$$A = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{1}{2} \left( (6 + 6 \sin \theta)^2 - \frac{81}{4} \csc^2 \theta \right) d \theta$$

I will leave the evaluation to you.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch in polar coordinates will reveal the following: [image: following]

You can work entirely in polar coordinates, but your first step is to find the polar equations of the blue and green rays in the first and third quadrants. Hint: Note that the required area is symmetric about the $y$-axis, so you can work exclusively in the first quadrant, then double. You can find the $\theta$ value of the intersection of the line $y = \frac 92$ and the cardioid in the first quadrant by finding the line's polar equation by $r\sin\theta = \frac 92 $, where $r = 6(1+\sin\theta)$. You should get a "nice" value for $\theta$ in radian measure (let's call that $\alpha$). Now use the polar area formula and find the integral $\int_{\alpha}^{\frac {\pi} {2} } \frac 12 r^2 d\theta$.  Note that to get the required area in the first quadrant, you need to subtract away that pesky right triangle bounded by the blue and black line segments and the $y$-axis, whose area you can quite easily determine. Finally double the result to get your answer.